# join в несколько уровней

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Пишу фильтр для сайта, необходимо использовать join в несколько уровней, в один уровень умею, а вот второй уровень не могу написать, ошибками закидывает.

В `property_product` находится связка товара и характеристики.
В `property` находятся сами характеристики.

Задача: получить `product` учитывая характеристики. Сначала берем из `property_product` товары с характеристиками, потом отсортировываем лишние, чтобы в `property` были совпадения. Желательно сделать в таком же виде, чтобы был один основной `join`, а всё остальное внутри него. То есть получаетс `join` в 2 уровня.

Вот, что я наворотил :D

```
$product = DB::table("product")
                ->join('property_product', function($join) use ($filter) {
                    if (!empty($filter) && !empty($filter['property'])) {
                        $join->on('property_product.id_product', '=', 'product.id');

                        foreach ($filter['property'] as $keyp => $valuep) {
                            $join->join('property', function($joinp) use ($valuep) {
                                $joinp->on('property.id', '=', 'property_product.id_property')
                                ->where('property.val', '=', $valuep['value'])
                                ->where('property.id_category', '=', $valuep['id']);
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Ошибка:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id_category' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select `product`.* from `product` inner join (`property_product` inner join `property` on `property`.`id` = `property_product`.`id_property` and `property`.`val` = 2 and `property`.`id_category` = 2) on `property_product`.`id_product` = `product`.`id` where (`id_category` = 1 and `id_city` = 1) and `id` = 1 limit 15 offset 0) in file /home/host/loc/shop/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 671
```

Comment: Если код порождает ошибки, то их обязательно надо указывать в вопросе

Comment: И желательно таки формулировать задачу, а не только свои неудачные попытки её решить. XY-problem.

Comment: @Ипатьев добавил

Comment: @Akina написано же, сделать join в 2 уровня

Comment: Это не задача. Это то, как Вы хотите некую неозвученную задачу решить. И соответственно XY - ибо не факт что выбранный метод правилен.

Comment: @Akina теперь лучше?

Comment: Вы почему-то мыслите итерациями. Нет никакого "сперва один отбор, потом из его результатов второй". Отборы равноправны. Вы просто делаете 2 связывания с двумя разными копиями таблицы свойств, и для каждого связывания используете свои условия. И не забудьте каждой копии таблицы свойств указать уникальный алиас. Схематично `table -> join(properties as p1) {p1.prop_name='name1' and p1.prop_val='value1'} -> join(properties as p2) {p2.prop_name='name2' and p2.prop_val='value2'}`

Comment: @Akina а можно для laravel и с данным кодом, который я вставил?

Comment: Да я в laravel ни ухо ни рыло... то есть могу, конечно, но потрачу много времени, чтобы написать это синтаксически корректно - вот оно мне надо? Идея есть, тот, кто работает в laravel, легко эту идею реализует кодом.

Comment: @Akina добавьте в ответ, что предложили, сработало.

Comment: Что добавить в ответ - вот этот типа шаблон? Ну несерьёзно.. лучше напишите самоответ с рабочим решением.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может быть легче использовать чистый sql?

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM table1, table2, table3
WHERE table1.id = table2.id and table2.id = table3.id
```